Which discount rate to use?
I am confused on various ways the discount rate can be estimated. For example, in CECL (Current Expected Credit Loss methodology) the discount rate for future cashflow is mandated to be used as something called Effective Interest Rate i.e. EIR, which is a single number.
However for typical Pricing model, the discount rate is to be estimated from various market traded contracts like OIS etc. In this case, we typically get a term structure of discount rate. Also the way these 2 different ways the discount rates can be estimated, are fairly different from my understanding.
Could you please opine if they are indeed different? And specific way of estimation to be used for the accounting purpose like CECL or actual trading.
Any pointer will be very helpful

If this is true there is no such mandate. Do you have an exact reference? In fact it smells like the typical accounting stuff that makes only consultants rich.

@KurtG. you reference indeed states that Finally, the discount rate (effective interest rate) is the contractual interest rate adjusted for any net deferred fees or costs and/or premiums or discounts existing at origination.. My question is exactly that i.e. why EIR as discount rate? Why cant I construct discount curve based on traded instrument and calculate PV?
